# Property 'jornada' does not exist on type 'NgModel' - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Es la primera vez que escribo aqui y la verdad es que llevo 4 horas con un fallo el cual no logro comprender.

El error es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no se que ocurre, en otros archivos si que me reconoce el NgModel, y he probado a copiar y pegando y reemplazando las cosas, y nada, no hay forma de que funcione.

Aqui la linea donde salta el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui el archivo .TS donde se supone que debe buscar 'jornada'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme! Un saludo y gracias de ante mano!

Comment: ¿Cómo está definida la clase Jornada?

Comment: `export class Jornada {

    constructor(
        public _id: string, 
        public jornada: string, 
        public color: string
    ){}
}`                           Justo igual que la clase de Usuario, pero con menos campos, y con esta clase si me funciona el ngModel

Comment: Con el modelo de Usuario todo funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de cambiar a este modelo (Jornada), me dice que no, que no esta definido en NgModel

Comment: Tengo los imports de FormsModule hechos correctamente en app.module tambien

Comment: yo creo que es por conflictos de variables. Si miras tienes una referencia en el input que se llama `#jornada` y luego ene la clase otra propiedad `jornada`. Puede ser por eso. Cambia la ref `#jornadaRef`

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y poner código en texto para poder copiarlo?

Comment: @hawks te debo la vida, ese era el problema. Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: @Zur gracias tambien por comentar y estar ahi!